# What's the difference between あって vs ありまして?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, て-form

I was taught that the て form of the verb ある is あって, but I sometimes see the word ありまして acting in the same way. What's the difference and when would you use one or the other?

Comment: ありまして comes from あります, the polite form of ある.

Comment: @MissLavelle I wasn't aware that the ます form could be conjugated on its own. I've tried to look into that, and I can't find any info about this for any verb aside from ある. And how is this different from just あって?

Comment: Blavius got to it before me, haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「ありまして」is just a really polite form of 「あって」.

In the standard polite sentence, only the final verb is put into the polite -ます form, while the rest are in the regular dictionary forms:

> 朝ご飯を食べてシャワーを浴びました。

While often overkill, it is possible to put the other connecting verbs into the -ます form as well. The resulting「まして」form has the same function as the regular connective -て form, just adding extra politeness- which is why it is common in keigo sentences.

> 解説を読みましても、理解できません。

Also, although this isn't really a problem with ありまして, one thing you should be aware of is that you cannot use the -まして in a request with ください.

> × 私の作った料理を食べてみましてください
>   ○ 私の作った料理を食べてみてください

Comment: 「朝ご飯を食べまして、シャワーを浴びました。」 does not look good.  Do they teach you to say that in Japanese-as-a-foreign-language?

Comment: No, I was trying to show how it worked based off the first example sentence. I'm aware it's not really used (which I probably should note, shouldn't I.)